# How do I use ResourceItemReader in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch and I need to create a custom reader using ResourceItemReader to get only resources names from .xml and .pdf files and pass to a class that represents them.

For example:

CustomReader read -> C:\teste\teste.xml, C:\teste\teste.pdf
-> Populate in Class Domain their resources.

Remering that I don't need to open the file, just get the resources.

Any idea how I could do ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to create a custom reader using ResourceItemReader to get only resources names from .xml and .pdf files

You don't need a custom reader for that. You can filter resources and pass only the ones you want to the reader:

```
Resource[] resources = .. // create an array of only pdf and xml resources
ResourcesItemReader reader = new ResourcesItemReader();
reader.setRresources(resources);
```